# Gradle: Applying from external gradle file which is downloaded as artifact

Tags: gradle

I have a test lrg.gradle file which is supposed to do the following

### lrg.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath group: '<group path>', name: '<gradle file>', version: "${Version}",
}
apply from <above downloaded gradle file>
```

---

I am looking on how to apply from the above downloaded gradle file. Where will the gradle file downloaded and which variable i need to refer to access the cached location. Assuming it is stored in GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches.

Basically we want to have this in all Test LRG files so that all common tasks and dependencies can be applied from common artifact gradle file. So that they can be used like dependent tasks for the tasks defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply from a URL like so:

```
apply from: "http://artifactory.url/maven/repo/$group/$name/$version/common.gradle"
```

That should allow you to avoid declaring a dependency on the common.gradle file.